# Meaning of sampling i.i.d rvs from (random) probability measure?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Quote from book: "Consider an arbitrary atomic probability measure $\Gamma$ on unit sphere. Let $(\sigma_{l})$ denote an i.i.d sample from $\Gamma$."

I don't understand the second sentence. Does it mean

Let $(\sigma_{l})$ be random variables mapping into the sphere. Then pick the ones, mapping into the support of $\Gamma$.

or

Pick points $(\sigma_{l})$ uniformly from the support of $\Gamma$.

So that in the case $\Gamma$ is a random measure (i.e. $\Gamma:\Omega\times \mathbb{S}^{n-1}\to \mathbb{R}$), the second sentence respectively says

Let $(\sigma_{l})$ be random variables mapping into the sphere. Then pick the ones, mapping into the most probable support of $\Gamma$.

or

Pick points $\sigma_{l}$ uniformly from the most probable support of $\Gamma$.

Thank you

(1)"The Sherrington-Kirkpatrick model" by D.Panchenko pg. 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that each $\sigma_i$ is a random variable (mapping into the sphere) with distribution given by $\Gamma$. Furthermore, $\sigma_1,\dots, \sigma_n$ are (stochastically) independent for each $n$.

Comment: what is the meaning of "distribution given by $\Gamma$"?

Comment: what if $\Gamma$ is non-random?

Comment: "With distribution given by $\Gamma$" means that $P(\sigma_i \in M)=\Gamma(M)$ holds for each (Borel) subset $M$ of the sphere. If $\Gamma$ is non random , i.e. if there is $x_0$ in the sphere with $\Gamma(\{x_0\})=1$, then $\sigma_i = x_0$ (almost surely). In general, since $\Gamma$ is a discrete measure, we just have $P(\sigma_i = x_j)=p_j$, if $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ is the support of $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma(\{x_j\})=p_j$.

Comment: @PhoemueX Does this imply that all the random variables sampled from the probability measure are identical in the sense that they define the same function? So what is the point to have n "iid" copies?

Comment: @PhoemueX I think I got it. thx for the answer.